# Do the symbol pages in The Founding and Manifesto of Zardulism mean anything?

Tags: ergodicity

[The Founding and Manifesto of Zardulism](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8_Q26dW1W2eZWNnOXF1VksyV0k/view)* has several pages that are... filled with symbols without clear meaning. It's only ten pages long, but three pages (5-7) are dedicated to what looks like encoded text.

Whether it actually encodes text, or if it's designed to *look* like it encodes text, is a little bit of a mystery. So... *does it*? If so, what does it say? If not, what are we supposed to make of the fact that it doesn't?

**(this link is the actual link to the document, as posted by Zardulu)*

Comment: I'm writing this to inform you that this question is currently untagged; I'd create a tag myself, except I don't know what to create. Also please add a usage guidance for the tag, otherwise it'll be rombaed again :D